# Change python version only in a single virtual environment

Tags: 18.04, bash, gnome, python3

Gnome terminal will only run when `python3.6` is used. So I created an environment and installed `python3.9` like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sudo apt install python3-venv
python3 -m venv test_env
source test_env/bin/activate

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
apt list | grep python3.9
sudo apt-get install python3.9
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.9 2
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
python3 -V
```

However this causes the whole system to switch to `python3.9` and prevents terminal from working. How can I prevent this?

Now, running `source ~/.bashrc` allows the non-venv terminal to continue working. And `python -V` reports the correct version of `3.6`. But if I close the window I can't reopen it. I have to use a terminal in my IDE to reselect the older version of python. Running:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3
```

Shows that actually, version `3.9` is selected. Even though `python -V` actuallt reports running `python3.6`:

```
# Python 3.6.9


#  Selection    Path                 Priority   Status
# ------------------------------------------------------------
#  0            /usr/bin/python3.9    2         auto mode
#  1            /usr/bin/python3.10   2         manual mode
#  2            /usr/bin/python3.6    1         manual mode
#* 3            /usr/bin/python3.9    2         manual mode
```

Comment: You did design this procedure yourself? Adding a PPA then installing python obviously will update the system version of python, and break your system.

Comment: No I did not, and as such I wasn't aware of what `PPA` did. I thought the problem was the way I setup my venv. Can I just remove the `PPA`?

Comment: Yes, using ppa-purge you can remove the PPA and undo the changes. I cannot help specifically with setting up different python environemnts, unfortunatelly.

Comment: Using the Deadsnakes PPA does **not** update the system version of python. Both versions exist simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

As outlined by Vanadium, using `PPA` updates the system version of python. So even from the venv I was making a global change.

The solution is quite obvious; Python3 doesn't run Python3, it runs whatever version of python3 is installed on the system, so in my case...

```
python3 -m venv test_env
```

Was setting up a python3.6 venv. Running...

```
python3.9 -m venv test_env
```

Appears to have correctly setup a python3.9 venv. To hammer home the point, in order to run python code in ATOM IDE using Hydrogen, in my 3.9 venv I had to run...

```
python3.9 -m ipykernel install --user --name=atom_venv_py
```

So it's just a case of specifying which version of python you want to use in every instance where it deviates from the sys version (IPython kernel is the Python execution backend for Jupyter which allows Hyrdogen to run).

Comment: No. Using the Deadsnakes PPA to install python3.9 will **not** replace the system version of python.

Comment: So they exist simultaneously, What dictates which version of python is used?

Comment: When you run `python3`, you get system's default python (which is 3.6 in Ubuntu 18.04). When you run `python3.9`, you get python3.9. And obviously, when you run `python3.6`, you again get python3.6. I have not tried it, but as you have written in your answer, `python3.9 -m venv test_env` should give the intended results.